# What is the units used for the `OpenEBS_read_latency` prometheus metric?

Tags: prometheus, openebs

Does anyone know in what units the OpenEBS_read_latency prometheus metric is?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's definitely not a Prometheus metric. It's a metric collected by Prometheus from some job or exporter. Check the documentation of that job/exporter for your answer. Or its `/metrics` page, maybe there is a useful description there.